# How Detect virtual keyboard events in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to monitor the key events of the virtual keyboard, including the keycode. RawKeyboardListener has no effect on virtual keyboard keys.

```
    void _onkeyclick(RawKeyEvent event) {
    if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
      if (event.data is RawKeyEventDataAndroid) {
        RawKeyDownEvent rawKeyDownEvent = event;
        RawKeyEventDataAndroid rawKeyEventDataAndroid = rawKeyDownEvent.data;
        print(rawKeyEventDataAndroid.keyCode);
        switch (rawKeyEventDataAndroid.keyCode) {
          case 66:
        }
      }
    }
  }
Widget getItem(Pbtem pb) {
    if (pb.type == 1) {
      TextEditingController _c = new TextEditingController();
      return new RawKeyboardListener(
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          onKey: _onkeyclick,
          child: new EditableText(
            controller: _c,
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            cursorColor: Colors.blue,
          ));
    } else if (pb.type == 2) {}
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us the  code of what you already tried?

Comment: I added some code. I tried these, I can get the physical keyboard key events, but I can't get the key events of the virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I solved it in this way. 
Try to get your cursor position index in the text via `TextEditingController` and with that index get last typed value.
Imagine below example is in `TextField`'s `onChanged` function which gives you inserted text.

Something like this

```
String key = value.substring(_textController.selection.end-1, _textController.selection.end);
```